# Stack level too deep (SystemStackError) when I add 'spec_helper'

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm upgrading an old `Rails 2.3 application` and finding most of the specs are failing.
I and am working to get them passing.

So far most of the spec files have not included require `'spec_helper'` but it needs to be added.
(not sure why it wasn't there before).

When I add the `spec_helper` to a few of the controllers I get the error stack level too deep `(SystemStackError).`

Im currently running as below but I beleive this was probably a Rails 2.1 app to begin with.

- Rails 2.3.17
- Rspec-rails 1.3.2
- Ruby 1.9.3

The top of the file looks like this.
The stack too deep error causes the set of tests to not actually run at all.
If I comment out the first three lines then the tests at least run, albeit all failing.

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'active_merchant'
include ActiveMerchant::Billing

describe 'AccountsController' do
...
```

This is the stack trace I've been able to get up after a bit of fiddling.

```
2)
stack level too deep
../bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
../gems/activesupport-2.3.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:170:in `load_with_new_constant_marking'
../gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@project/gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:15:in `block in load_files'
../rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14:in `each'
../gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14:in `load_files'
../gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner/options.rb:134:in `run_examples'
../gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner.rb:61:in `run'
../gems/rspec-1.3.2/lib/spec/runner.rb:45:in `block in autorun'
../gems/activesupport-2.3.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:186: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Where to from here?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `include ActiveMerchant::Billing` into the describe block as follows:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'active_merchant'

describe 'AccountsController' do
  include ActiveMerchant::Billing
  ...
```

#### References:

- [A previous Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9255879/429758)
- Blogpost by Dave Chelimsky titled [RSpec waving 'bye bye' to implicit module inclusion](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2008/05/29/rspec-waving-bye-bye-to-implicit-module-inclusion/)