# Model with "method missing" behaves differently in Rails 4 than Rails 3 (can cause 'stack level too deep' error)

Tags: rspec, upgrade, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails application that was working fine with Rails 3.2.14. I have just started to work on upgrading it to Rails 4, essentially following along with [Railscast episode 415](http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4?view=comments).

I got as far as the part where I try to run my rspec tests to find many now fail with the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 SystemStackError:
   stack level too deep
```

I also checked my Cucumber tests and find similar failures.

```
stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

As everything was fine before I started upgrading, I have been searching for other experiences that are similar but haven't found any.

I have tried both Ruby 1.9 and 2.0. I have not modified any code

Any guidance appreciated.

**Update:**

I have tracked the problem down to a model thatat defines `method_missing` as part of its implementation. I have described what I have found in a [separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18368456/712506) so that it can be commented on separately.

My application contained a model that implemented its own `method_missing` which could cause a recursive loop that ultimatly concluded in the "stack level to deep" error.

Comment: Not an answer per se, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247071/rspec-stack-level-too-deep for how to approach.

Comment: The problem also happens on a `rake db:seed`. I believe it is due to my app recursively including model subdirectories (`config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', 'content_items')]`). I have replicated the behaviour in a new test app and am now investigating that...

Comment: Please see my update to the original question. The stack overflow is merely a symptom of a model that defines a method `method_missing`. There is a definate behavioural difference in Rails 4 when `method_missing` is defined in a model.

Comment: Nice work! I just searched and while I found an apparently related https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F16088392%2Fdefining-method-missing-on-active-record-in-rails-4-throws-systemstackerror-sta&ei=ePgUUuDZFu_wyAGcoIHADA&usg=AFQjCNFVivCMCoIOv_Kyc05ak4Sh8-upyQ&sig2=e3G6G539pel_LgPDSzNvhA&bvm=bv.50952593,d.aWc, I didn't see this called out in any release notes.  You might want to factor our your explanation in a separate answer where folks can clearly see it (and upvote it!).

Comment: And unless you think the recursion is entirely unique to your situation, you might want to even restore the title in order to help others with this symptom find it.

Comment: thanks. I have separated it out as per your suggestion. I think my recursion problem was due to how the model was coded. It just wasn't expecting `method_missing` to be called for every use of an accessor!!! All I need to do now is find out how this scenario should be handled in Rails 4.

Answer (score 3):

Per suggestion, there is sufficient detail to warrant separating this as an answer.

I have tracked the problem down to a model that defines `method_missing` as part of its implementation. I have found that, if there is a `method_missing` definition in the model, then it is called **instead of any accessors**. This causes any model set-up to fail.

(in my specific case, method_missing was defined and this is what caused the stack overflow that I mentioned originally).

I can reproduce the problem succinctly by defining a new rails app in Rails 3.2.14 and then creating a new model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :content
  store :content

  def method_missing(id, *args) 
    puts "method missing: #{id}"
  end
end
```

and the associated migration

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :content

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

If I run a rails console I can exercise the model:

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.14)
2.0.0p247 :001 > x = Item.new(name: 'foo')
 => #<Item id: nil, name: "foo", content: {}, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.0.0p247 :002 >
```

If I build exactly the same thing in Rails 4.0.0 I get different output:

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)
2.0.0p247 :001 > x = Item.new(name: 'foo')
method missing: name=
 => #<Item id: nil, name: nil, content: {}, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.0.0p247 :002 >
```

You'll notice that, in Rails 3.2.14, the `name` attribute is set to `foo` as is the intention. In Rails 4.0.0, however, see that `method_missing` is called and the attribute is not set.

I am reading up on the changes to ActiveRecord but I haven't been able to find anything that suggests models using `method_missing` which were ok prior to Rails 4 would no longer be ok in Rails 4.

Any pointers to getting the code example able to work in Rails 4 would help me solve the problems that I have with my model.

**UPDATE**

By manually invoking the upward `method_missing` chain, I can get the above example to work:

```
  def method_missing(id, *args) 
    super
    if respond_to? id
      send(id,*args)
    else
      puts "method missing: #{id}"
    end 
  end
```

Needing to do this feels wrong to me because it isn't clear why this behaviour changed between Rails 3 and 4. I feel I am missing something else...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the change was either, but you can avoid calling super for non-accessor methods by checking `respond_to_without_attributes?`. This is used in the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7f1b3c15f7c55003dbd9b83d3a2468002161977d/activemodel/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb#L434)

```
  def method_missing(method, *args) 
    super if respond_to_without_attributes?(method, true) # returns true when attr accessors

    if respond_to? method
      send(method,*args)
    else
      puts "method missing: #{method}"
    end 
  end
```