# query , can not select column count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

```
Tag.joins(:quote_tags).group('quote_tags.tag_id').order('count desc').select('count(tags.id) AS count, tags.id, tags.name')

Build query:
SELECT count(tags.id) AS count, tags.id, tags.name FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `quote_tags` ON `quote_tags`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id` GROUP BY quote_tags.tag_id ORDER BY count desc
```

Result:

```
[#<Tag id: 401, name: "different">, ... , #<Tag id: 4, name: "family">]
```

It not return count column for me. How can I get it?

Comment: Does it work when you select only `count(tags.id)`?

Comment: yes, But it return only count column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried calling the `count` method on one of the returned `Tag` objects? Just because `inspect` doesn't mention the `count` doesn't mean that it isn't there. The `inspect` output:

```
[#<Tag id: 401, name: "different">, ... , #<Tag id: 4, name: "family">]
```

will only include things that the `Tag` class knows about and `Tag` will only know about the columns in the `tags` table: you only have `id` and `name` in the table so that's all you see.

If you do this:

```
tags = Tag.joins(:quote_tags).group('quote_tags.tag_id').order('count desc').select('count(tags.id) AS count, tags.id, tags.name')
```

and then look at the `count`s:

```
tags.map(&:count)
```

You'll see the array of counts that you're expecting.

Comment: It return a array nil: [nil,nil,nil,...]
Result I want is tags.id,tags.name and count.

Comment: Have you tried calling the count something else just to make sure you're not getting a conflict with something else?

Comment: No, Just like my query above

Comment: @Peter_175 Would you mind sharing the code that gave you the `nil: [nil, ...]` result?

Comment: @muistooshort: Sorry, I understood wrong the way you lead me. My english is a little bad. You right! I think count is conflig with other name (method of ruby or something else). when I change it to 'size'then I can get that column :D

Comment: @Peter_175 I know it's working for you with the name `size`, but it might really help others if we can get to the bottom of why `count` is not working for you. If you could post the code you're using which gets the `nil: [nil, nil, nil ...]`, I bet we can figure out what's going on.

Comment: @Peter Alfvin: Actually I don't understand what wrong. Now I run my old query (count), I can get it. suprise and confuse XD
Ahh, maybe in the pass I have attr_accessor :count. And then when I remove that I not restart console yet in that time

Answer (score 1):

Update: The original version of this answer mistakenly characterized `select` and subsequent versions ended up effectively repeating the current version of the other answer from @muistooshort. I'm leaving it in it's current state because it has the information about using raw sql. Thanks to @muistooshort for pointing out my error.

Although your query is in fact working as explained by the other answer, you can always execute raw SQL as an alternative.

There are a variety of `select_...` methods you can choose from, but I would think you'd want to use `select_all`.  Assuming the build query that you implicitly generated was correct, you can just use that, as in:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all('
  SELECT count(tags.id) AS count, tags.id, tags.name FROM `tags`
    INNER JOIN `quote_tags` ON `quote_tags`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id`
    GROUP BY quote_tags.tag_id
    ORDER BY count desc')
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html for information on the various methods you can choose from.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I just did a `Model.select('count(id) as count').map(&:count)` and got a count back.

Comment: I don't believe the `count` method you've invoking corresponds to the count column in SQL. If I use `as foo` and `map(&:foo)` I get a `method not found` error, although it works with `count`.

Comment: Yeah, if you do `User.select('count(id) as count').method(:count)` you get `=> #<Method: ActiveRecord::Relation(ActiveRecord::Calculations)#count>`

Comment: One thing I found that was interesting is that if you use the name of an existing field for your count column name using the `select` method, ActiveRecord will go ahead and put the count results in that field in the records it synthesizes.

Comment: Actually it is the right count, changing it to `as x` and `&:x` yields the same result. And note that there is a difference between the methods involved in `User.select('count(id) as count').method(:count)` and `User.select('count(id) as count').map(&:count)`.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for the follow-up.  I'm sure you're right and am looking forward to understanding this, but will have to get back to it tomorrow.

Comment: @muistooshort Ok, I see that I was doing the `.method` on the `ActiveMethod::Relation`, but even if I select one of the elements, I still get the `undefined method error`. I gather what's going on, though, is that ActiveRecord is catching intercepting the `undefined method` and returning the data that it has stored internally.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'd guess that `method_missing` is behind the shenanigans, Rails loves to make things up on the fly and all the magic can be very confusing. I wonder if MySQL (the OP) vs PostgreSQL (me) is causing some confusion with the `count` name as well. Knowing about the "do it by hand with SQL" approach is worthwhile, the first rule is "get the job done" :)

Comment: @muistooshort  think you're right about `method_missing`, although coincidentally there seems have been a change in all that with Rails 4 per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287707/model-with-method-missing-behaves-differently-in-rails-4-than-rails-3. I'm not sure what's going  on with the OP, though. I sorta doubt the database difference explains what they're reporting, which is why I asked to see the code. I'm using Postgres as well, FWIW.

Comment: I've seen my share of bizarre things in AR that require throwing things at the wall to see what sticks and adventures through the source code to figure out. This could be one of those.